# Putting <div> inside <td> dynamically using Jquery (vai xml parsing)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml-parsing

i need to get id of div which i am creating inside a 
my code is:

```
    tab_Div = $ ('#id_of_table')
    $(xml).find('something').each(function(i){
    value1 = $(this).attr('some_attribute');
    newID = "divID_"+i;

    var my_row = $('<tr><td>'+value1+'</td><td><div id="'+newID+'"></div></td></tr>').appendTo(tab_Div);

    drawBar(value1,newID);
    //This function draws progressbar of "value1" in the div whose id is "newID"
});
```

theoretically, this function should add a row to a table having two cells
1. which display value 
2. progressbar of that value.

but i think , it has a problem with 'id' of 'Div'. and "newID" is a string not 'id' of any obj

can anybody help me on this ???
pls tell me how can i draw desired table (i.e. with progressbar in one cell)

code of drawBar()

```
function drawBar(no,eid)
    {
        $(eid).progressbar({value: no});
        $(eid).css({background: '#99FF66'});
        $(eid+" > div").css({background: '#009900'});
        $(eid+" > div").css({border: 'none'});
    }
```

drawbar function just draws a jqueryUI progress bar into DIv which it receives at "eid"

Comment: what is yuor drawBar(value1,newID) function do ????? , can you post the code

Comment: i add drawBar() to my question,,   i am just calling `$(id).progressbar(value:something)`  of JqueryUI progressbar

Answer (score 1):

hi i have seen your code and found that you have not closed the div tag inside your td 
EDIT: not only the div tag is not closed but u have also passed wrong variable of table `tab_Div` you have passed `tab_div`

```
  tab_Div = $ ('#id_of_table')
    $(xml).find('something').each(function(i){
    value1 = $(this).attr('some_attribute');
    newID = "divID_"+i;

    var my_row = $('<tr><td>'+value1+'</td><td><div id="'+newID+'" ></div></td></tr>').appendTo(tab_Div);

    drawBar(value1,newID);
```

EDIT AFTER THE COMMENT:

FOLLOWING IS THE CODE:

```
<body>
<table id="id_of_table" style="width:50%; border:1px solid red; float:left" >
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){

    tab_Div = $ ('#id_of_table');
    for (var i =1; i<=10; i++){
        value1 = "test";
        newID = "divID_"+i;
        $('<tr><td>'+value1+'</td><td><div id="'+newID+'" >i m inside div </div></td></tr>').appendTo(tab_Div);
}
    //drawBar(value1,newID);


});


</script>
</body>
```

The above code work fine, when u are appending it to table why are you passing it to the variable `my_row` not required. try my code in HTML page, remember to add jQuery file.

Comment: @ Murtaza !!!   sorry, that was a typing mistek here , .. i corrected it now.  but in actual code there is no such a mistek

Comment: i use `my_row` variable to change css properties of newly created row later on.

Comment: have you checked commenting the drawbar function once, i think there is an issue with your `$(xml).find('something').each(function(i){})`

Comment: ya ! i checked them both, table is getting created, drawBar() also receives id correctly... but i think drawBar is receiving only string of id , not actual id.... there is some issue in `<td><div id="'+newID+'"></div></td>` line

Comment: so can you try passing the control to `drawBar` by `$("#" + newID)` I have never tried such thing. but it should work., instead of passing the id, select the control and pass to your `drawBar` function. **Note** update your `drawBar` function according to the change in parameter

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way i've found to generate a unique enough id in javascript is to get properties from a Date object.

```
var date = new Date();
var id = "" + date.getHour() + date.getMinutes() + date.getSeconds() + date.getMilliseconds();
```

to track IDs that have been created you can use an array

```
var _ids= new Array();

...

$(xml).each(function(i) {
  ...
  newID = "divID_"+i;
  _ids.push(newID);
});
```

then, when you need to access the divs you can just go through the array

Comment: `newID = "divID_"+i;` creates a different id for me in each iteration . my problem is totally different , all i want is create <div> inside <td> and access 'id' of that newly created div .

Comment: so you need a way to track the IDs that have been created?  you can add them to an array

Comment: Ya !!  i need to pass those IDs to a function in each iteration. can u pls tell me how can i make this work ?

Comment: i updated my answer to show one way to use an array to track the ids

Answer (score 0):

i think this code is wrong

```
<div id="'+newID+'"</div>
```

please change it to

```
<div id='+newID+'></div>
```