# How to divide or display the 'div' data as mulitple columns in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my page large data is there, around 200 items. I need to display one by one means new row like that. It's occupying so much space need to scroll to see all the data.
I decided to display that 200 items as 4 or 5 columns. Please tell me how to do that?
Please suggest me any good idea to display 200 (large data) in a page. Any samples let me know?

**How to Dynamically populate multiple coulmns in html ?**
If suppose 200 items are there divide it as 4 columns first column as 50,2nd column as 50 and 3rd and 4th also 50.if 201 item added it should dynamically need to add in first coulmn .How to acheive this using html?

Thanks

Comment: why @michal  u pointing negetive?

Comment: It's not me. Just fixed spelling. You got negative probably because your question doesn't show research effort.

Comment: i am asking suggestions @Michal .once got idea i will do that

Answer (score 0):

Displaying 200 at a time its not much big task but its depend on your data first 
analyze your data 
check images size if exists 
and then decide how much data to display 
There  so many links available in jquery check lazy loading of jquery

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

https://plugins.jquery.com/lazy/

Answer (score 0):

Put those divs inside `<td></td>`. Be more specific about how you want to do whatever you are trying to do for better answers

Comment: Same div data how to split and put it in seperate td's?

Comment: What kind of data you are talking about? From where are you getting those data to your page? It will be helpful if you show us some code snippet.

Comment: You might find your answer [here][1].
[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586846/putting-div-inside-td-dynamically-using-jquery-vai-xml-parsing

Comment: seperate div data into muliple coulmns each row should display 40 items.